# BeautifulSoup: Why .select method returned an empty list?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to simulate the 'click' action with the BeautifulSoup so that I can scrape the page returned. I tried selenium webdriver and BeautifulSoup, but I got an empty list every time. In the following code I copied the selector -- my last attempt, but it still doesn't work.

```
# Scraping top products sales and name from the Recommendation page

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.961206468.1594951946; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1594951949275.1940955365; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_F=y1evilme0ImdfEmNWEc08bul3d8toc33; REC_T_ID=fab983c8-c7d2-11ea-a977-ccbbfe23657a; SPC_SI=uv1y64sfvhx3w6dir503ixw89ve2ixt4; _gid=GA1.3.413262278.1594951963; SPC_U=286107140; SPC_EC=GwoQmu7TiknULYXKODlEi5vEgjawyqNcpIWQjoxjQEW2yJ3H/jsB1Pw9iCgGRGYFfAkT/Ej00ruDcf7DHjg4eNGWbCG+0uXcKb7bqLDcn+A2hEl1XMtj1FCCIES7k17xoVdYW1tGg0qaXnSz0/Uf3iaEIIk7Q9rqsnT+COWVg8Y=; csrftoken=5MdKKnZH5boQXpaAza1kOVLRFBjx1eij; welcomePkgShown=true; _ga=GA1.1.1693450966.1594951955; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; REC_MD_30_2002454304=1595153616; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1595152099.14.1.1595153019.0; REC_MD_41_1000044=1595153318_0_50_0_49; SPC_R_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="; SPC_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_R_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="'
}
shopee_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/top_products'

navi_info = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0')
# extracts all the "index" data from all "sections"
index_arrays = [object_['index'] for object_ in navi_info.json()['data']['sections']]
index_array = index_arrays[0] # only one section with "index" key is present
# extract all catIDs from the "index" payload
catIDs = [object_['key'] for object_ in index_array]
params = {'catID': catIDs}
print(params)

# a = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
response = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/top_products', params=params)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
products = soup.select('#main > div > div.shopee-page-wrapper > div._3b-UMP.container > div > div.stardust-tabs-panels > section:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a')
print(products) # Why this returns an empty list? 
for product in products:
    name = product.select_one('#main > div > div.shopee-page-wrapper > div.page-product > div.container > div.product-briefing.flex.card._2cRTS4 > div.flex.flex-auto.k-mj2F > div > div.qaNIZv > span')
    sales = product.select_one('#main > div > div.shopee-page-wrapper > div.page-product > div.container > div.product-briefing.flex.card._2cRTS4 > div.flex.flex-auto.k-mj2F > div > div.flex._32fuIU > div.flex.SbDIui > div._22sp0A')
    print(name)
    print(sales)
```

Answer (score 2):

my guess is that you're including build artifacts in your css selector chain.

ie  `div._3b-UMP.container` and `div.product-briefing.flex.card._2cRTS4`. They're probably not consistent across builds and sessions. You'll want to rewrite your selectors to not use any build artifacts

Comment: Could you be more specific? Because I'm not very familiar with front-end knowledge and I just started to learn web-crawler yesterday. Much thanks.

Comment: Since you're new to web development, you'll want to learn about css selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

css selectors are how you specify html elements to your select() and select_one() functions. 

your current selectors are very specific. The `>` means direct child, so you're looking at id = main, with a child of div, with a child of div of class shopee-page-wrapper, etc etc. 

you'll want to find a selector that selects the elements you're interested in on the page in question.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, since it sounds like you're not the owner of the page, the page structure may change at a moment's notice and break your scripts, as is the problem with web scrapers in general.

Comment: I went to check the source page, and I guess that the reason that I got an empty list is that there is no 'div' in the source page. If I am right, then how can I scrape the content that I am looking for?

Comment: you have to inspect the html source and figure out what the consistent pattern is in the tags and classes. Since this page you're looking at is dynamically generated, there could be all sorts of ways that the content isn't easily accessible to the scraper due to lazy loading content. either you have to use a long timeout to wait for all page resources to render and resolve, or you have to watch any ajax queries and wait for them to resolve, which wouldn't work in the case of polling.

Comment: with web scraping these days, there's a degree of reverse engineering of the site in question. you've got to determine a consistent structure. Try experimenting in the console with various css selectors to see if they're grabbing the right info for you consistently.