# BeautifulSoup: find_all() returns an empty list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

After checking the source page of the website I am crawling, I guess the reason that I could not fetch the content I wanted is that there's no div element in the source page. I also tried using css selector (in another question [BeautifulSoup: Why .select method returned an empty list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004432/beautifulsoup-why-select-method-returned-an-empty-list)), but that won't work either. Here's some of my code:

```
# Scraping top products sales and name from the Recommendation page

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.961206468.1594951946; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1594951949275.1940955365; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_F=y1evilme0ImdfEmNWEc08bul3d8toc33; REC_T_ID=fab983c8-c7d2-11ea-a977-ccbbfe23657a; SPC_SI=uv1y64sfvhx3w6dir503ixw89ve2ixt4; _gid=GA1.3.413262278.1594951963; SPC_U=286107140; SPC_EC=GwoQmu7TiknULYXKODlEi5vEgjawyqNcpIWQjoxjQEW2yJ3H/jsB1Pw9iCgGRGYFfAkT/Ej00ruDcf7DHjg4eNGWbCG+0uXcKb7bqLDcn+A2hEl1XMtj1FCCIES7k17xoVdYW1tGg0qaXnSz0/Uf3iaEIIk7Q9rqsnT+COWVg8Y=; csrftoken=5MdKKnZH5boQXpaAza1kOVLRFBjx1eij; welcomePkgShown=true; _ga=GA1.1.1693450966.1594951955; _dc_gtm_UA-61904553-8=1; REC_MD_30_2002454304=1595153616; _ga_SW6D8G0HXK=GS1.1.1595152099.14.1.1595153019.0; REC_MD_41_1000044=1595153318_0_50_0_49; SPC_R_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="; SPC_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_R_T_IV="IETR5YkWloW3OcKf80c6RQ=="; SPC_T_ID="Am9bCo3cc3Jno2mV5RDkLJIVsbIWEDTC6ezJknXdVVRfxlQRoGDcya57fIQsioFKZWhP8/9PAGhldR0L/efzcrKONe62GAzvsztkZHfAl0I="'
}
shopee_url = 'https://shopee.co.id/top_products'

navi_info = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0')
# extracts all the "index" data from all "sections"
index_arrays = [object_['index'] for object_ in navi_info.json()['data']['sections']]
index_array = index_arrays[0] # only one section with "index" key is present
# extract all catIDs from the "index" payload
catIDs = [object_['key'] for object_ in index_array]
params = {'catID': catIDs}
print(params)

# a = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
response = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/top_products', params=params)
print(response.text)
soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': '_3S8sOC _2QfAXF'})
print(products) # Why this returns an empty list? 
for product in products:
    name = product.select_one('#main > div > div.shopee-page-wrapper > div.page-product > div.container > div.product-briefing.flex.card._2cRTS4 > div.flex.flex-auto.k-mj2F > div > div.qaNIZv > span')
    sales = product.select_one('#main > div > div.shopee-page-wrapper > div.page-product > div.container > div.product-briefing.flex.card._2cRTS4 > div.flex.flex-auto.k-mj2F > div > div.flex._32fuIU > div.flex.SbDIui > div._22sp0A')
    print(name)
    print(sales)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to scrape if the element isn't in the source? Maybe it's added dynamically using JavaScript, so you'll need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to emulate that.

Comment: Do you mean using WebDriver to emulate the action of the mouse clicking or what? I tried this and I found that the source page of the products is the same as https://shopee.co.id/top_products. And so I cannot scrape any useful data like sales or product name either.

Comment: Also how am I supposed to use the WebDriver click the element if I couldn't find it?

Comment: You don't need to click anything, you just need to execute the JS that happens when the page is opened.

Comment: But if you do, Selenium has methods for that. It allows you to write a script that emulates the actions of a browser.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know JS either, so could you please be a little more specific about "execute the JS that happens when the page is opened"? Much thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218244/discussion-between-leonard-lee-and-barmar).

Comment: I don't know the details of Selenium, but I don't think you need to know JS. You tell it to perform browser actions like load a page and click a button.

Comment: If you inspect the source code of the page with the dev tools of your browser, you will see that in fact there are alot of divs

Comment: Also if you want to soup the page you need to scrap the **content**: `response = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/top_products', features = "lxml", params=params).content`

Answer (score 0):

You get no items in the `find_all()` list, because in the page (HTML) there are no tags with that class: `'_3S8sOC _2QfAXF'`

You can check this easily scraping all the elements with this class:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

response = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/top_products').content
soup = bs(response,"html.parser")
products = soup.find_all(class_ = "_3S8sOC _2QfAXF")
```

Note here that I am scraping the `content` attribute and also using the `class_` kwarg in the `find.all()` method, to get all the elements with this specific class.

Unfortanaly there are no elemets. ://

```
print(products)
```

give back:

```
[]
```